# Xcode's problem of converting 3d model on DAE format for ARKit

Tags: xcode, crash, arkit, collada, cinema-4d

I got 3D model from my graphic designer on `.dae` file format. When I was trying to open this model in the Xcode – the Xcode app was crashed. 
After I see this problem, my graphic designer tried to convert 3D model from `.fbx` and `.c4d` to `.dae` with different methods, but it's not helped. We used 3ds Max, Blender, Cinema4d for converting to `.dae` file format.

I need to use this 3D model for ARKit project.

[image]

This is our
[model look in MacBook Preview on video](https://youtu.be/4VJMORpXXG8)

Correct 3D model on `.fbx` format.

[image]

Comment: Give me a link to your 3D model (thru file sharing service) and I'll try to convert it into `.dae` format.

Comment: I'm sorry. But i can't give you link to 3d model. Because, It's commercial 3d model and i have not permission from owner. Can you explain how do you will export 3d model on .dae?

Comment: I have new information. This 3d model use mixamo stucture bones from web-service mixamo.com. My problem is related to the unreadable structure from misato on Xcode.

Comment: Ok, this changes the game.

Comment: I remove bones from 3d model in Cinema4d, after export on .dae format. Model is show correctly without any problems, but without animation.

Comment: Right now, I found a solution to my problem on this site.[Animating a 3D model in AR with ARKit and Mixamo](https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/)

Comment: Yep, this is a good post. I read it a year ago.

Comment: Sorry, ArGeo.My english is not good.

Comment: It's ok, don't worry. ))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182716/discussion-between-akbako-and-argeo).

Comment: I think its a bug from Mojave because if you want to open in finder look like a buggy image, we need to wait to apple fix this